# How safely bring lamp wire into house?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, outdoor, weather-resistant

I'm considering replacing an outdoor lighting fixture with an LED motion-sensitive fixture, but I'm not sure how to safely do the wiring.

The location is protected (under a porch) but still needs to be weatherproof. Here's the existing fixture and mount:

[image: Current outside fixture]

The obvious replacement would be another lamp that included its own box cover, so that its wiring would be covered and protected. But, the fixture I like doesn't include such a cover:

[image]

You can see it's meant to be screwed into the wall, but doesn't cover anything. The power cable ends with bare wires which are meant to be wire-nutted to the supply wiring, probably inside a junction box. But, how do I get the wire safely into the junction box while keeping things weatherproof?

One option would be to replace the lamp's power cable with one ending in a grounded plug, and install a weatherproof outlet box. But that's ugly and complex.

Are there weatherproof junction box covers that include provisions for sealed entry of cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those cheap Chinese lights need to be thought out better. There is no one stock part to simply mount them to a proper box. You'll need to make something up on your own. Some of the ones I've seen at the supply house have been put together with a plate from the manufacturer with a rubber sealed connector already installed.

You'll need to mount the bracket to a gasketed weatherproof blank place, then knock out or drill a hole for a rubber cord connector of the proper size to pass the cord through the metal plate.

If you do not have the light yet my strong recommendation would be to find one that is already set up to mount to a box properly.